# Limit of an iteratively defined sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

Let $d>0$ be a fixed real number. Define a sequence $(a_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ as follows: let $a_0 = 0$, and

$$a_{k+1}:=a_k + \frac{1}{d+a_k}$$

for each $k\geq 0$. Does this sequence go to $\infty$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence is increasing *(why?)*, so it converges in $[0,\infty]$.

If the sequence were to converge to some $\ell\in[0,\infty)$, then $\ell$ would satisfy *(why?)*
$$
\ell = \ell + \frac{1}{d+\ell}
$$
which is impossible *(why?)*. So the sequence diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: I can see the first why is because it's monotonic. But the second why...

Comment: @ougoah If $\lim _{n\to\infty } a_n  = a$ and $f$ is continuous, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) = f(a)$. Apply that to both the LHS and RHS of your recurrence relation.

Comment: Nice technique!